# What arguments are missing from my Perl LWP command?

Tags: perl, lwp

I'm trying to pull a photo from a webcam, and save it to a file.  This is the command:

```
/usr/bin/perl -MLWP::Simple -e 'getstore "https://website.com/image”,”/home/images/image.jpg"'
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

*Not enough arguments for LWP::Simple::getstore at -e line 1, at EOF*

What arguments are missing from my LWP:Simple command?  The manual for LWP does not explain much regarding the "-e" option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you have some non-ASCII quotes in there. Specifically the 2nd and 3rd are U+0201D RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK. Because of that, Perl is reading `"https://website.com/image”,”/home/images/image.jpg"` as a single string. So you've only passed one argument to `getstore`.

> *The manual for LWP does not explain much regarding the "-e" option.*

`-e` is an option for perl itself, not LWP::Simple. For more on `-e` see [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html).

Comment: That was it, thanks!  I've been trying to read up on LWP and I wasn't having much luck.  As for the option, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.